# Change colors using one button javafx

Tags: button, javafx, colors, event-handling

How should I use my Buttons(red and blue).

Got four buttons on my pane. Two of them to draw the shapes circle and square on to the pane, and two to color them with either red or blue.

I want the color Buttons to only paint the last shape Button(Circle1 or Square) I clicked on.

Any suggestions?

```
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        Button circle = new Button("Circle");
        Button square = new Button("Square");
        Button red = new Button("Red");
        Button blue = new Button("Blue");
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(circle, square, red, blue);

        Rectangle Square = new Rectangle();
        square.setOnAction(e -> {
            Square.setX(200);
            Square.setY(200);
            Square.setHeight(75);
            Square.setWidth(75);
        });

        Circle Circle1 = new Circle();
        red.setOnAction(e -> {
            Square.setFill(Color.RED);
            Circle1.setFill(Color.RED);
        });

        blue.setOnAction(e -> {
            Square.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            Circle1.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        });

        circle.setOnAction(e -> {
            Circle1.setCenterX(100);
            Circle1.setCenterY(100);
            Circle1.setRadius(45);
        });

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.getChildren().addAll(Square, Circle1, hBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 600, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ShowBorderPane");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Any suggestions for what? What is the problem you're trying to solve here?
Note: Try to learn naming conventions in Java and use them.

Comment: Yeah sorry i didn't explain well. I got two buttons, one to paint red and another for blue. I also have two shapes on my pane, square and circle. What i want is to paint ''one at a time'', not both as my current code does.

Comment: What do you mean one at a time like you want to add some time between 
 each of their color changes? just add `Thread.sleep(2000);` between them

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60300318/edit) your question and try to explain the problem you are having to an imaginary five year old. Your title says "Changing between two colors with one button javafx" but then the code shows 2 buttons and what your explaining in the comments matches up with neither of those now you want to paint them "one at a time" figure it out

Comment: hopefully i made it easier to understand now

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: "_I want the color Buttons to only paint the last shape Button(Circle1 or Square) I clicked on_" – Add a mouse-pressed (or -clicked) handler to each shape and store which shape was clicked on last (e.g. in a field). Then simply have your button change the color of the last-clicked-on shape.